# How to trim a result field in an EJS template?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I currently use a simple EJS template to display blog posts:

```
<main>
        <% results.forEach(function(results){ %>
      <article>

              <section>
                   <h2><a href="/soccer/<%= results.id %>" title="<%= results.title %>"><%= results.title %> </a></h2>
        <p>


          <%= results.body %> 

            <label for="<%= results.id %>" class="margin-toggle sidenote-number"></label>

        </p>

                   <input type="checkbox" id="<%= results.id %>" class="margin-toggle"/><span class="sidenote"><%= results.date%></span> 

          </section>
      </article>

             <% }) %>
```

I would like to trim the date field

```
<%= results.date%>
```

I did try `results.date.substring(1,10)` but it returns substring not defined.

Comment: Why do you not prepare the value in the backend? You should do it in the backend, to keep the frontend as logic free as possible

Comment: @elsololobo this is a very good point but I think EJS has this capability so it is interesting to see how it works. After all, if one wants logicless templates, it could use mustache ;)

Comment: try `String(results.date).substring(1,10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be `results.date` is not string. You should convert `date` value to string

```
<%= results.date.toString().substring(1,10)%>
```

Or:

```
<%= '' + results.date.substring(1,10)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String(results.date).substring(_,_)
```

It should work, I had the same issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
String(results.date).slice(_,_)
```

Worked for me in this situation.

I hadn't realized at first that my date was not a string and thus needed to be casted as one. MYSQL was inserting -0400 GMT EASTERN TIME and wanted to remove that portion, thus my need for this.